# Redirect FROM controller AFTER Ajax call (including parameters)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

So, I have a small problem and I would like to know if there is any possibility of solving it in the following manner, I know there are other ways to go about the issue but I want to know if it could be possible to solve it like this:

I have an ajax call, a GET.  On this ajax call I just want to pass some parameters based on user input (through javascript) and have the controller-action handle the rest.  The problem is that, with ajax, the success function takes care of whatever happens after the action has completed.

I have a redirect on my action (ActionResult which returns a View with some parameters), I want to allow the controller to redirect me here, but ajax kicks in with the Success function.

How can I pass the full path (which can change since it is based on user input) to the success function in order to redirect?

Thank you!

```
 public string Edit(string stringEventID)
    {
        Guid eventID = new Guid(stringEventID);

        if (eventID == Guid.Empty || eventID == null)
        {
            return Url.Action("Edit", "MyController", new { area = "MyArea", id = new Event() });
        }

        else
        {
            Event _event = _iEMARepository.Events.Where(p => p.EventID == eventID).SingleOrDefault();

            return Url.Action("Edit", "MyController", new { area = "MyArea", id = _event })
        }
    }
```

Comment: My problem is not whether the request succeeded or not, I want the controller to redirect, regardless. But the url won't be the same, it'll depend on user input. How can I return the full path and redirect through window.location.href after that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Url helper to construction the URL properly for MVC and your routes.  Then return a `Jsonresult` with the URL (you may need to set AllowGet):

```
string url = Url.Action(your arguments here);

return new JsonResult()
{
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
    Data = new Dictionary<string,string>() { { "url", url } }
};
```

Than use the url in success function to trigger a redirect:

```
success: function (data) {
    window.location.href = JSON.parse(data)['url'];
}
```

Comment: Returning a string would definitely do the trick.  I'm just wondering how javascript handles URLs, since I know it's different from how MVC handles them.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I can "skip" the success function in this case, or not even use ajax at all (I believe this last one won't work since I am basing the redirect on user input and thus, need to send the parameter to the controller)

Comment: Correct, you'll definitely want to call to the server in order to construct the URL.  You will want to actually use the success function because you probably won't want to redirect if there is an error on the server or a problem with the ajax call.

Comment: Right, I'm sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but would I have to construct the string from scratch then? As in with StringBuilder so I can add a {0} at the end (the parameter)?

Comment: I'll update the answer with how to construct the URL for MVC.

Comment: Awesome! I'm assuming maybe a .ToString() at the end? I'll try this out.

Comment: `Url.Action()` returns a string.

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer and I would also appreciate if you would upvote it because I think someone prematurely down voted it.

Comment: I'll upvote :) I noticed one problem with this, I need to return an object and unfortunately the url returns this: "http://localhost:51492/MyArea/MyController/MyAction/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Event_359DB148E9BE49C3560F4091F1A66D789EDFFDB5E6F1355DE31AA51E1A568D49"

which of course, is not the correct route

Comment: What do you mean you need to return an object?  Why is the route incorrect?

Comment: For example, and I'm sorry for not posting my code, I'll update it. The action returns a View(MyObject) where, MyObject is the object being used to build that view. I'll mark your answer as correct, because based on my question it would be the way to go, but I think you set me in the right direction. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Oh I see.  I think what you want is to return that `JsonResult` I showed you instead.  Then when the javascript redirects to the URL you returned it should target an action that will return what you were returning previously, i.e. `View(MyObject)`.

Comment: I believe there is also a mistake with my logic. I should probably add a second action, which is called when ajax is first fired. On success, call the first action and redirect as planned.  Does that sound like a plausible option?

Comment: Yep I believe that is what you want to do.  One action for the ajax call to return the URL and another action that will be invoked by that URL.